Using `DescribeSpec` for unit tests, what is the name of my test for kotest filtering in gradle?
kotest exposes a kotest_filter_tests environment variable to run only tests which match the value, i.e. *IntegrationTest, in a gradle test task (see Kotest doc).
I use DescribeSpec for my unit tests, such that unit test classes look like this:
import io.kotest.core.spec.style.DescribeSpec

class MyUnitTestClass: DescribeSpec({
   describe("Some test group") {
      describe("GIVEN some condition") {
         it("does something") {
           ...
         }
      }
   }
   ...

In the test in the above example class, what value does kotest respect as the name of the test for filter matching?
Setting kotest_filter_tests to combinations of describe and it descriptions have resulted in not matches.

describe and it are not test names but merely the names of functions to create tests. Test names in your example are "GIVEN some condition" or "does something".
